# Creating Hibernate SessionFactory using persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, persistence

Is is possible to create hibernate `SessionFactory` object from `persistence.xml`.
Usually we create `EntityManagerFactory` using `persistence.xml` , I would like to know if `SessionFactory` could be created.
I googled it but did not find any useful resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of Hibernate that supports JPA 2.1, you can use the `unwrap` method on the `EntityManagerFactory`: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)

If what you are really after is a Hibernate `Session` object, you can get that from the `EntityManager` object using the `getDelegate` method.